# sed delete all besides first and last line of many files

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'd like to process many *.txt files in a directory - they have a common structure (; separated, common headers) **but** vary in the number of lines each is comprised of i.e. some are just a single line, others up to 8 lines long..

I would like to delete any lines other than the first and the last line for each file. Any helpful pointers?

**Update:** I've included some test data files as requested:

stat87.txt

```
Stations_id; Stationshoehe; Geogr.Breite; Geogr.Laenge; von_datum; bis_datum; Stationsname;                                                                                                             
 87;     ; 46.1123;  8.5440;19010101;19661229;Dres
```

stat01.txt

```
Stations_id; Stationshoehe; Geogr.Breite; Geogr.Laenge; von_datum; bis_datum; Stationsname;                                                                                                             
 1;     ; 47.8400;  8.8500;18910101;19580228;Aach                                                                                                                                                   
 1;  478; 47.8413;  8.8493;19580301;19860630;Aach
```

and stat56.txt for example.

```
Stations_id; Stationshoehe; Geogr.Breite; Geogr.Laenge; von_datum; bis_datum; Stationsname;                                                                                                             
 56;     ; 46.4580;  7.6320;18980101;19450321;Hamb
 56;     ; 46.4580;  7.6320;19450321;19880511;Hamb                                                                                                                                                   
 56;  103; 46.4411;  7.6345;19880601;19990630;Hamb
```

In this case I'd be especially looking to keep the first line of columns 5 and the last of column 6, so that the time-span of the station is captured.

**Results:**

```
find . -type f -name \*.txt -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -I xxxx sed -ni '
2 {
  $ {
    s/^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\).*$/\1;\2/
    p
    q
  }
  s/^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;\([^;]*\).*$/\1/
  p
}
$ {
  s/^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;\([^;]*\).*$/\1/
  p
}' xxxx
```

generates....

```
19010101;19661229

18910101
19860630

18980101
19990630
```

I then use a simple sed loop to clean up the final files, by adding the ;

```
'for file in *.txt; do
  sed 'N;s/\n/;/' "$file" > "cleaned$file"
 done'

19010101;19661229

18910101;19860630

18980101;19990630
```

Comment: OK, the title says "delete first and last", the text says "delete any lines other than the first and last". What's true?

Comment: @choroba sorry, after midnight this part of the world..

Comment: What should happen to single line and two line files?

Comment: @choroba stay as is if possible. The meta-step I would like to  complete is keep only column 2 of line 1, and column 3 of the last line for example.. These mark the start and endpoints of the variable I need.

Comment: @kleanBean You should provide 2 or 3 data files content example and also an example of the expected result.

Comment: I think this is pretty easy, but we'd be needing some sample output for the input as well.

Comment: @kleanBean a very last edit to provide a awk only version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfect, there is below the awk only version:

```
find . -type f -name \*.txt -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -I xxxx sed -ni '
 2 {
   $ {
     s/^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\).*$/\1;\2/
     p
     q
   }
   s/^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;\([^;]*\).*$/\1/
   h
 }
 $ {
   s/^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;\([^;]*\).*$/\1/
   H
   x
   s/\n/;/
   p
 }' xxxx
```

Thank you to the very famous [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Results:

```
$ cat stat01.txt
18910101;19860630
$ cat stat56.txt
18980101;19990630
$ cat stat87.txt
19010101;19661229
```

### ----

---

**first version for reference**

Based on your input, I invented data file format and a sed script to work them.

Give this a try:

```
$ find . -type f -name \*.txt -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -I xxxx sed -ni '
 2 {
   $ {
     s/^[^;]*;\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\).*$/\1;\2/
     p
     q
   }
   s/^[^;]*;\([^;]*\).*$/\1/
   p
 }
 $ {
   s/^[^;]*;[^;]*;\([^;]*\).*$/\1/
   p
 }' xxxx
```

It removes the first line which contains the headers.

It keeps only column 2 of the first data line encountered and the column 3 of the last data line of the file.

If a file contains only one data line, it keeps on one line column 2 and column 3.

hehehe this is odd, but I had a lot of fun !!!

The data files in the current directory:

```
$ cat test01.txt
Name;Price;Amount;Description
Bread;2.1;3;healthy one
$ cat test02.txt
Name;Price;Amount;Description
Water;0.0;100;For life
Wine;10.3;1;Less than half a glass a day
$ cat test03.txt
Name;Price;Amount;Description
House;1000.0;1;home
Car;500.5;0;no need
Bike;10.3;5;Good for the planet and for me
```

Results:

```
$ cat test01.txt
2.1;3
$ cat test02.txt
0.0
1
$ cat test03.txt
1000.0
5
```

Please provide 2 short data files content and the expected result, and I will modify this answer.

Comment: thanks!! works perfectly. added my code for the above example files..

Answer (score 0):

You will need a loop over the files for that:

```
for file in *.txt; do
  lines=$(wc -l < "$file")
  if [ "$lines" -lt 3 ]; then
    echo "$file is short enough, not touching it."
  else
    # for testing, you can also use the -i option
    sed -n '1p;$p' "$file" > "$file.new"
  fi
done
```

The loop is necessary if you have files that are only one line long.  With the [command given by thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273249/88313) they will turn up twice (try `echo 1|sed -n '1p;$p'`).

Comment: `sed -n '${p;q;};1p'` avoids that problem.  Making the whole loop reducible to `for file in *.txt; do sed -i -n '${p;q;};1p' "$file"; done`

Answer (score 0):

Gawk is a much better tool for this task than sed. Repurposing the original approach's find-xargs pipeline and using the same output nomenclature:

```
find . -type f -name \*.txt -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 gawk -F\; '
    FNR==2  { von = $5 }
    ENDFILE { print von FS $6 > "cleaned" FILENAME }
'
```

The code is made much simpler, much clearer, and eminently more maintainable.